# How do free SMS apps like Pinger work?

Tags: mobile, text, sms

I want to build an app whose core functionality is essentially the same as Pinger and other free SMS apps - that is, it needs to allow for texting without going through your phone's service provider by sending the data over the web. But I can't find any APIs or explanations as to how this is accomplished.

Pinger assigns you a phone number to use, which I assume means it must also run its own SMS gateways. But I don't know how to do either of these things (assign valid phone number and create SMS gateways), or whether I can even do them on my own and purely programatically. Does anybody know where I can find this information?

TL;DR: Essentially, I need to know how to create my own Pinger/free SMS app. My app will be different, but will employ the same underlying functionality.

Answer (score 2):

SMS messages are not free to send and this is why Pinger's business model is based on advertising when you send and receive their messages, see http://www.pinger.com/content/advertise.html

In order to do this yourself you would need to work with one of the companies that offers a SMS gateway. You could use a whole bunch of different providers, take a look at this post I previously made with some of them [How to send SMS programatically in a professional and reliable way?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10929635/how-to-send-sms-programatically-in-a-professional-and-reliable-way/10949136#10949136)

I also add, you would need to work out a suitable business model to pay for the SMS messages you plan to send :-).